# CoreBluetoothFramework - Does it launches the IOS application when it is not running

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, core-bluetooth

Can anybody tell me if the CoreBluetooth Framework is able to launch the application (to inform the application when it detects a new device using bluetooth). when the application is not running in the background. Also i would like to know the situation when the application is running in the background. As per the documentation this framework will launch the application from the suspended state. Could anybody share some information on this as i dont have an Iphone 4S to test this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you launched the application when the application detects new device

Answer (score 4):

As far I know, the only way to launch an app without user intervention is when your app uses VoIP services. To detect a Bluetooth LE (BTLE) device, the CBCentralManager instance needs to be running in the background of an app designed by you. Else, there is no way to detect a BTLE device which is in the vicinity. 

If you are designing your app, core-bluetooth has two types of backgrounding enabled.Event and Session.

**Event Backgrounding**
Event backgrounding is probably what most Apps will use when interacting with Bluetooth Low Energy devices.  This mode does not allow for direct communications to the accessory when the App is in the background, but does provide for a notification from the accessory when it wants to communicate with the app.  iOS will stay connected to the BTLE accessory when your App is in the background and will continue to monitor for notifications.  When the connected BTLE accessory has a notification available, iOS will notify the user that the accessory would like to talk to your App, allowing the user to load your App and interact with the accessory.  As many devices need to conserve power, only providing information at deterministic times will greatly enhance the battery life of the accessory and the iPhone 4S.

- No info.plist entries are required for this mode.

**Session Backgrounding**
There are times where an App must interact with an accessory even if it is running in the background.  Consider a running app that needs to monitor heart rate real-time.  There is a clear START and STOP to this model.  The user STARTS their run in the App. While the run is active, the App reads heart rate information until the run is completed or STOPED.  Session backgrounding also allows for scanning and connection to BTLE accessories while the App is in the background.  A scanForPeripheralsWithServices or connectPeripheral call will continue, even when the App is in the background.  CoreBluetooth will continue to monitor for specific peripherals or peripherals that match the services your App is looking for and call your Apps delegate when found or connected.  Be mindful, that every time a BTLE peripheral or iPhone 4S uses its radio, it is depleting the respective devices available power.  App developers using session based backgrounding must be mindful of power usage.

- Session backgrounding requires a backgrounding mode entry to UIBackgroundModes, bluetooth-central, in your Apps info.plist.